# Godot: Extract all data from a tree node

Tags: tree, godot

Godot 3.5.1: I have been trying to extract all data from the PlayerTable tree node without success. Attempts to use `.get_item_at_position` have only resulted in the return of `[Object:null]`. Ultimately, I want to extract the cell values (see screenshot) and use them to create instances of my Player class.

[image]

So far, my code looks like the following, but I'm afraid that I'm off by a mile.

```
func create_players():
    for i in range(player_table.get_child_count()):
        var name_vector = Vector2(i, 0)
        var species_vector = Vector2(i, 1)
        var color_vector = Vector2(i, 2)
        var type_vector = Vector2(i, 4)

        var player_name = player_table.get_item_at_position(name_vector)
        var player_species = player_table.get_item_at_position(species_vector)
        var player_color = player_table.get_item_at_position(color_vector)
        var player_type = player_table.get_item_at_position(type_vector)

        print("i = " + str(i))
        print("player_name = " + str(player_name))
        print("player_species = " + str(player_species))
        print("player_color = " + str(player_color))
        print("player_type = " + str(player_type))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you know, you can set the number of columns of the `Table` by setting the `columns` property. And you can set their titles with `set_column_title`.

Then, to populate the `Table`, you add items with `create_item`. These items are `TreeItem`, and not `Node`s. The first one you add will be the *root* of the `Table`, and subsequent items will default to be parented to the *root* unless you specify a different parent.

I presume you have hidden the parent node (by setting `hide_root` to `true`). And that every item you are interested in is parented to that *root*.

---

Now, `get_child_count` will give you the number of children nodes. Of which you shouldn't have added any. *Again, the items of the `Table` are not children nodes*. However, you are not going to get zero from `get_child_count`. The reason is that Godot will add children nodes behind your back to implement the `Table` UI. But these children are a `PopupMenu`, a `LineEdit`, some bars, sliders and timers and you should not worry about.

And `get_item_at_position` is graphical. It is useful, for example, to find out over which item the mouse is hovering over.

None of that is what you want.

---

Instead, you can get the *root* of the `Table` with `get_root`. To reiterate the *root* of the `Table` is a `TreeItem` and not a `Node`.

Then you can get the first item parented to the *root* by calling `get_children`, and then you can iterate over the siblings with `get_prev` and `get_next` (they return `null` if there aren't more items). *In Godot 4, `get_children` actually returns an array, but up to Godot 3.x we are stuck with this.*

Each `TreeItem` has the values for each column (i.e. each `TreeItem` is a row). And you can get them with `get_text` (it returns `String`).

---

Thus, your code would be something like this:

```
    var root_item := player_table.get_root()
    var current_item := root_item.get_children()
    var i := 0
    while current_item != null:
        var player_name := current_item.get_text(0)
        var player_species := current_item.get_text(1)
        var player_color := current_item.get_text(2)
        var player_type := current_item.get_text(3)

        print("i = " + str(i))
        print("player_name = " + player_name)
        print("player_species = " + player_species)
        print("player_color = " + player_color)
        print("player_type = " + player_type)

        current_item = current_item.get_next()
        i += 1
```